# Slug in Korean not working in Django even with 'allow_unicode=True'

Tags: python, django, slugify

I'm trying to make an automatic slug using the slugify in `django.utils.text`. The following are my code:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
# article_create.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="create-article">
        <h2>Awesome New Article </h2>
        <form class='site-form' action="{% url 'articles:article_create' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="create">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
# html template - article_lists.html

...
<a href="{% url 'articles:article_details' article.slug %}"></a>
...
```

I used the allowed_unicode=True in order to allow different languages to be used, but the following error comes up when I type in Korean in the title in the form:

[image]

The first underlined is the title of the article that I'm trying to post, and the second underline is the Django backend checking the slug, but I see that it doesn't recognize the Korean letters... I did what all the other similar StackOverflow, including putting the `allow_unicode=True`, but it's not working. What must be wrong here???

*edit: This is the `urls.py` code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'articles'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.article_list, name="article_list"),
    path('create/', views.article_create, name="article_create"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.article_details, name='article_details'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason to this! it wasn't working it was because of the `urls.py`

**Before:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'articles'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.article_details, name='article_details'),
]
```

**After:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'articles'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<slug>/', views.article_details, name='article_details'),
]
```

I had to change the `<slug:slug>` to `<slug>`... I really don't know the reason why and maybe it's just for in Korean, but this was the right way for me.

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing what you defined in the `urls.py` file for the given route. You could change the route `articles/?P<slug>...` to include more than just `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Then the reverse lookup should be able to match the slug.

Comment: I added the urls.py code... I don't think it's really wrong

Comment: I guess the `path()` uses a simple regex that isnt enough for your requirements. Maybe defined the url regex manually.

Comment: I'll try and edit the question when finished.